# Better way to write Monoid for Filter returning Disjunction in Scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am trying to implement a monoid for `Filter`. (It is the same as `Reader[A, Boolean]` in *Scalaz*)

```
type Filter[A] = A => Boolean
```

The easiest way to implement filter is,

```
implicit def monoidFilter[A] = new Monoid[Filter[A]] {
  override def zero: Filter[A] =
    a => false
  override def append(f1: Filter[A], f2: => Filter[A]): Filter[A] =
    a => f1(a) || f2(a)
}

// test
case class User(name: String, city: String)
val users = List(User("Kelly", ".LONDON"), User("John", ".NY"), User("Cark", ".KAW"))

// filtered: List(User(Kelly,.LONDON), User(John,.NY))
(users filter (london |+| ny) size) shouldBe 2
```

I found that this is `Disjunction`. Now we can `mappend` without `monoidFilter`

```
import Tags._
import syntax.tag._

val london = (u: User) => Disjunction(u.city endsWith(".LONDON"))
val ny     = (u: User) => Disjunction(u.city endsWith("NY"))

(users filter { u => (london |+| ny)(u).unwrap }).size shouldBe 2
```

But the code becomes longer in terms of usability.

So my question is, There is a better way to implement `monoidFilter`? I though it is already implemented in *Scalaz* but I couldn't find yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `Monoid[A => Boolean]`

You actually can stay with original alias

```
type Filter[A] = A => Boolean
```

If you would like specifically `or` monoid you easily construct such instance

```
import scalaz.std.anyVal._
import scalaz.std.function._

implicit def boolMonoid[A] = function1Monoid[A, Boolean](booleanInstance.disjunction)
```

This will significantly simplify the syntax

```
val london: Filter[User] = _.city endsWith ".LONDON"
val ny: Filter[User] = _.city endsWith "NY"

users filter( london |+| ny)
```

### `Rig[A => Boolean]`

But if I were you, I would use [`Rig`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/spire/stable/0.11.0/unidoc/#spire.algebra.Rig) ([semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring)) from the [spire library](https://github.com/non/spire#rings-co) instead of `Monoid`.

I don't know if there are libraries that can lift `BooleanRig` to `Function1` monad, but it's easy to make it by hand:

```
import spire.algebra.Rig

implicit def filterRig[A] = new Rig[Filter[A]] {
  def plus(x: Filter[A], y: Filter[A]): Filter[A] = v => x(v) || y(v)
  def one: Filter[A] = Function.const(true)
  def times(x: Filter[A], y: Filter[A]): Filter[A] = v => x(v) && y(v)
  def zero: Filter[A] = Function.const(false)
}
```

Or even more general version

```
import spire.std.boolean._

implicit def applicativeRigU[MX, X](implicit G: Unapply.AuxA[Applicative, MX, X], rig: Rig[X]): Rig[MX] = {
  val A: Applicative[G.M] = G.TC
  val L: G.M[X] === MX = Leibniz.symm[Nothing, Any, MX, G.M[X]](G.leibniz)
  val rigA = new Rig[G.M[X]] {
    def plus(x: G.M[X], y: G.M[X]): G.M[X] = A.lift2(rig.plus)(x, y)
    def one: G.M[X] = A.point(rig.one)
    def times(x: G.M[X], y: G.M[X]): G.M[X] = A.lift2(rig.times)(x, y)
    def zero: G.M[X] = A.point(rig.zero)
  }

  L.subst(rigA)
}
```

Now you can add another filter like

```
val nameJ: Filter[User] = _.name startsWith "J"
```

And run

```
import spire.syntax.rig._

users filter (london + ny * nameJ)
```

Comment: It seems that *spire* provides the capability to combine different monoid operations (e.g `+`, `*`). Thanks for the nice solution and more powerful alternative.

Comment: @1ambda Yes. It's specifically distinguishes multiplicative and additive monoid typeclasses for such needs

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understand your question, but `Disjunction` or `\/` in `scalaz` is like [`Either`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/Either.html) in scala lib but a bit more different. With `Disjunction` you can model values that can be different types in the same time like:

```
val file = \/.fromTryCatchNonFatal( scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt") )
```

Here is `file` can be of type `BufferedSource` or `Throwable` when for example `file.txt` does not exist.

```
file: scalaz.\/[Throwable,scala.io.BufferedSource] = -\/(java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (No such file or directory))
```

Now you can map and filter over this value.
In your case `monoidFilter` is good approach to model boolean predicates.
I hope that it makes sense to you.

Comment: I think author means `scalaz.Tags.Disjunction` not `scalaz.Disjunction`